# How to execute this HABTM console association in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model, and two models that inherit from that: Teacher and Student. They also have their own controllers that inherit from the User controller.

I also have a Group model.

group belongs to teacher, teacher has many groups. group has and belongs to many students. student has and belongs to many groups.

There is a join table for the HABTM relationships, called 'groups_students'.

I have managed to create a form element that allows me to set the 'type' of User to 'Student' or 'Teacher'.

The difficulty I have now is assigning students to groups in the view. I can do this in the console no problem, as outlined here: [Rails 4 HABTM how to set multiple ids in console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223974/rails-4-habtm-how-to-set-multiple-ids-in-console/29227188#29227188)

I'm stumped as to how to do this in a view. I want to do it in the Student's show view.

Can someone at least give me some guidance? I have a pretty good book on Rails, but I need to know roughly what I have to do.

Comment: Your code needs to go in the question for your question to be on-topic for Stack Overflow. Please remove the github link and include the minimal amount of code required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I actually paid someone to solve this for me, because I couldn't find any free help for this on the internet. Thankfully, it wasn't *too* easy for him to solve, but solve it he did:

views/users/show.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag assign_to_group_path do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>
  <%= select_tag :group_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Group.all, "id", "title") %>
  <%= submit_tag "Assign to Class" %>
<% end %>
```

users_controller.rb:

```
private
def user_params
  params[:user].permit(:type) if params[:user]
end
```

students_controller.rb (inherits from users_controller.rb):

```
def assign_to_group
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @user.groups << @group unless @user.groups.include? @group
  @user.save!
  redirect_to user_path @user
end
```

routes.rb:

```
post 'assign_to_group' => 'students#assign_to_group'
```